# Uninstalling Ubuntu from Windows Dual Boot if I don't have Windows recovery CD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, 16.04, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu (I had already had Windows 8.1) from USB (I still have live Ubuntu on it). Is there a way I can uninstall Ubuntu in a way that my Windows will remain bootable? All the tutorials I have seen say that uninstalling ubuntu will delete GRUB also so I will need a Windows recovery CD to boot into it, but I don't have one. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create  a recovery drive using these steps:

> ## To create a USB recovery drive
>
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap Search. (If
>    you're using a mouse, point to the lower-right corner of the screen,
>    move the mouse pointer up, and then click Search.)
> 2. Enter recovery drive in the search box, and then tap or click Create
>    a recovery drive.  Administrator permission required You might be
>    asked for an admin password or to confirm your choice.
> 3. After the recovery drive tool opens, make sure the Copy the recovery
>    partition from the PC to the recovery drive check box is selected,
>    and then tap or click Next.
>
> ***Note**:
>  The checkbox is greyed out when your PC doesn’t have a recovery partition. The recovery drive will include only the recovery
> tools and a bootable image, but not a recovery image to use for
> refreshing or resetting your PC.*
>
> 1. Insert a USB flash drive into your PC that is at least as large as
>    the size indicated on the screen.
> 2. Tap or click the USB drive you would like to use for your recovery
>    drive, then tap or click Next.
> 3. Tap or click Create.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive)

---

## Backup!

Create a system image:

> ## How to Create a System Image
>
> In order to create a Windows 8 system image, the step-by-step
> instructions given below should be followed:
>
> 1. Log on to a Windows 8 computer with the administrator account.
> 2. Click the Desktop tile from the Start screen to go to the desktop.
> 3. Once on the desktop screen, hover the mouse to the bottom right
>    corner.
> 4. From the displayed options, click Settings.
> 5. From the Settings pane, click Control Panel.
> 6. On the Control Panel window, click System and Security category.
> 7. On the System and Security window, click File History from the right
>    pane.
> 8. From the left pane of the File History window, click Windows File
>    Recovery option at the bottom.
> 9. On the Windows File Recovery window, click Create a system image
>    from the left pane.
> 10. On the Create a system image window, click to select On a hard disk
>     radio button.
> 11. Once selected, click Next.
> 12. On the Confirm your backup settings page, click Start backup to
>     initiate the backup process.
> 13. Wait until the Windows 8 system image is created.
> 14. On the displayed Create a system repair disc box, click No to skip
>     the system repair disc creation process.
> 15. Back on the Create a system image box, click Close.
> 16. Once done, close the Windows File Recovery window.

[Source](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-make-system-image-backup,26542.html)

---

## Next,

Boot your computer from the USB drive you just created.
You should see this:
[image]

Click on "Repair your computer". You should see this:
[image]

Click on the "Troubleshoot" box. You should see this:
[image]

Click on the "Command Prompt" box.

## Once you have the CMD prompt

Simply enter the commands:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootrec.exe /fixboot
```

And then reboot the computer. It should automatically boot to Windows.

## Finally,

Back in Windows, use Disk Management to erase the Ubuntu partition.

---

*Images used are credit of the HowToGeek*

Comment: @Android_Dev Thanks but are you sure this will work?

Comment: @Nesa - I've done this on a machine running Vista. It worked fine. But, **make a backup first!**

Comment: @Android_Dev a backup of my personal files or something else?

Comment: See "backup" section of my edited answer.

Comment: @Android_Dev but doesn't this system image creation require a big disk to store all the data? I only have a 4 GB USB

Comment: Correct. You need a USB HDD >= the amount of space used on your internal disk. You can proceed without backing up, but **I won't be responsible if you fail to do a backup** and lose some data. I'm **not** saying that's it's likely you'll loose data, but there is always a risk.

Comment: @Android_Dev So the system image creation is fully optional if I don't care about my data?

Comment: You don't need to create a system image for this procedure to work. All I'm saying is that **if** something happens to go wrong, and you didn't make a backup, and you lost some data, I will not be responsible.

Comment: It hasn't yet I will do it at the weekend.